# Send 2 arguments to react redux middleware instead of just one action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, middleware, react-redux

I want to pass in a boolean value as the 2nd argument to my `actionCreator` which would determine what my middleware dispatches, but how do I give my middleware access to this 2nd argument? 
Do I have to dispatch an array or object instead of a promise?

```
export const fetchPokemon = function (pokemonName, booleanValue) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    dispatch({type: 'REQUESTING'})
    const requestURL = `http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemonName}/`
    dispatch(fetch(requestURL))
  }
}
```

**Middleware**

```
const fetchPromiseMiddleware = store => next => action => {
  if (typeof action.then !== 'function') {
    return next(action)
  }
  ...
  return response.json()
  }).then(function (data) {
    if booleanValue {
      store.dispatch(receivePokemon(formatPokemonData(data)))
    } else {
      store.dispatch(fetchPokemonDescription(data.name))
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems you have answered yourself, the action you dispatch should contain all the relevant data.
The simplest option seem to be to add a property (or properties) to your action, as a Promise is already an object.

```
export const fetchPokemon = function (pokemonName, booleanValue) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    dispatch({type: 'REQUESTING'})
    const requestURL = `http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemonName}/`
    dispatch(Object.assign(fetch(requestURL), {
      someNameForYourBooleanParameter: booleanValue
    })
  }
}
```

and

```
const fetchPromiseMiddleware = store => next => action => {
  if (typeof action.then !== 'function') {
    return next(action)
  }
  ...
  return response.json()
  }).then(function (data) {
    if (action.someNameForYourBooleanParameter) {
      store.dispatch(receivePokemon(formatPokemonData(data)))
    } else {
      store.dispatch(fetchPokemonDescription(data.name))
    }
  })
}
```

If you want to continue this path, I'd recommend to put these values under a `.payload` property to prevent any collision with members of the `Promise` class

I'd take this approach further to avoid the multiple actions being dispatched for the same logical action:

```
export const fetchPokemon = function (pokemonName, booleanValue) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    const requestURL = `http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemonName}/`;
    dispatch({
      type: 'REQUESTING',
      promise: fetch(requestURL),
      payload: {
        someNameForYourBooleanParameter: booleanValue
      }
    })
  }
}
```